# Data: One Big, or a bunch of small chunks?

Tags: c#, stream, uart

I am currently sending 128 packs of 64 bytes each across a BlueTooth connector.

This comes from an embedded system and is delivered to a C# GUI which displays the data with graphs. I am doing the code on the embedded system. I did not write the code on the GUI; but I'm pretty sure that it's using multiple threads for the UART stuff and the graphing stuff. Each sample turns out to be 64 bytes long.

We are now going to add USB to the options of available data paths.  (Currently we have Bluetooth and a UART).

I could duplicate the scheme and send the same set of 128 blobs of 64 bytes.

I could also rearrange the data (I think) and send one blob of 8,192 bytes in one swoosh.

Either way will require a sizable chunk of work for me.

**Question:** Will the single bigger blob give me an improvement on the throughput ? Or should I stick with a whole bunch of smaller blobs and let all the threads have their time to get their chores done ?

Comment: @AdamRobinson is probs right - best to measure the different approaches.  I am not sure if there is a constant answer for this sort of question.  Surely it depends so much on hardware conditions, and whether you are running in 32bit/64bit environments and all sorts.  Not really my strength, but I think its a fair assumption.  :)

Comment: Good answer is ugly.  I will have to write a lot either way. +1 for Adam

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved using the Nyquist sampling theorem.

[Nyquist Sampling Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)

Basically, if your screen only updates 60 times a second, and your system is able to receive enough data in 60 seconds to properly update the graph in real time - then getting higher throughput doesn't really get you anything.  You just get finer granularity on the curve that you are graphing.  If what you are currently getting is accurate enough, then going for higher throughput is just extra work.

If you need to analyze the line extremely accurately, higher throughput will be useful for getting all those extra data points.  This is basically a juggling problem between the resolution of the graph, the speed of the refresh of the screen, and the rate at which data is sent from the chip to the computer.

As a good rule of thumb, anything over 200 datapoints a second is over kill for visuals on most straightforward signals that doesn't have crazy high frequency spikes all over the place.  Depending on what is done with the data it may or may not be overkill.  This really depends on the signal that you are analyzing.  If it has an extremely high frequency, you'll need to sample more often to capture the signal in your datapoints.